# Binary search algorithm does not work properly - Java

Tags: java, algorithm, search, binary, do-while

I want to make my own binary search algorithm to search ArrayList of 1 000 000 elements. I decided to do the search with do-while loop. I am aware I could use while() loop. But when I run it, it takes much time to find the number. I guess something is wrong with setting the value of first and last element of ArrayList. My code is

```
import java.util.*;

public class BinSearchAlg {
public static void main(String[]args){

    int first;
    int last;
    int median;//middle element of arraylist
    Long element;//element with median index
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Long>list = new ArrayList();
    for(long l=0;l<1000000;l++){
        list.add(l);//list is sorted
    }
    first = 0;
    last = list.size();
    median = (last-first)/2;
    element = list.get(median);
    System.out.println("Choose the number: ");
    long l = scan.nextLong();
    do{
        if(element<l){
            first = median;
            median=(last-first)/2;
            element = list.get(median);
        }else{ //if(element>l){
            last = median;
        median = (last-first)/2;
        element = list.get(median);
        }
    }while(element!=l);
}
}
```

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `median` calculation is problematic:

```
median=(last-first)/2;
```

You should rather do:

```
median=(last+first)/2;
```

In the current code you have, when you are searching in the range `[10..16]`, your code will try to compare the goal with the median of `list.get(3)`.

There could be another bug, but for now I'll leave you with this. Hint: try `[0, 1]`, which should expose the bug in the code.

Comment: And `first = median + 1;` instead of just median. Further `while (first < last)`.

Comment: @JoopEggen yeah, I didn't give OP the answer, but added a hint.

Comment: @UmNyobe um, any reason for using that? Could it work without set fst = med + 1?

Comment: @ZiyaoWei If the list is large enough, `first + last` can overflow. `(last - first)/2 + first`, or, as UmNyobe wrote, `(first - last)/2 + last` cannot overflow (for `0 <= first <= last`).

Comment: @DanielFischer Ah I see. Thanks! (Although before overflowing, the memory probably ran out first under most circumstances, and we can always use long8) )

Comment: I think `ArrayList`s only accept `int` indices, so if you use `long` for the computations, you need a cast. Nowadays, on 64-bit systems, it is a practical possibility to have arrays (or `ArrayList`s) large enough that the `first + large` computation can overflow a 32-bit integer. It used to be a theoretical problem, as currently the overflow problem is with 64-bit integers for indices (that'll stay theoretical for a couple of years still).

Comment: @DanielFischer True, I just did a estimate and added the long comment. Thanks for pointing out a real world issue:)

Answer (score 0):

As Ziyao Wei answered, you'll need to fix the median.  In addition, you'll probably need a different loop exit condition - right now you've got an infinite loop if `l` isn't in the list.  Also, your `if-else` needs to be an `if-elseif-else` - at present if `l == element` then the loop will actually treat this as `element > l` and continue looping.

Comment: Ok, I used median=((last-first)/2)+first in my code. I also used if(element>l){last = median-1; ...}, then I added else if(element==l){break;} and else if(!list.contains(l)){break;} and used while(first<last); instead of while(element!=l); Now it seems it works. What do you think?

Comment: Take out `!list.contains(1)` - this will do a linear search of the entire list.  Instead, replace it with `else break;` to exit the loop when you've found the element.

Comment: Done. Is the rest of the code right? Does binary search work now?

Comment: I think your code should return a boolean to indicate whether the element was found.  Other than that it looks like it's ready for testing.

Comment: When I type any number in the range of the list, program will finish after a few miliseconds - in addition I used System.currentTimeMillis() method to count how much time has been taken between choosing the number and finding it.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use Collection class's binary search method present java.util package :-

```
Collections.binarySearch(myList,key.get(i),new MyTransferObjectClass());
```

and

```
public class MyTransferObjectClass implements Comparator<MyTransferObjectClass>{

@Override
    public int compare(MyTransferObjectClass o1, MyTransferObjectClass o2) {
                //your logic for comparison
    }

}
```

why to add redundant code when you can use available APIs.